# How can i use a thousand separator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 SELECT count(id) FROM table a
```

it gives me a number lets say 36136, how can i make thousand separator on top?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Presentation layer is usually a separate thing and shouldn't be mixed up in queries, unless there's a specific reason for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (MSSQL)

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, COUNT(ID)),1)
        ,'.00','') ,',','''') 
    FROM TABLE A
```

Example

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY, 1000),1),'.00','') ,',','''') X
```

Output

```
X
----
1'000
```

Comment: But I agree with Sami, unless it is strictly necessary for you.

Comment: I dont have a number in it SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table f, as a result it gives a number for ex 8000

Comment: Could you explain better, please?

Comment: For Ex i have this SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table f, and it gives a number back for ex 46000. but i need the number as 46'000 wit a thousand separator, how can i achieve this on the sql management studio?

Comment: Have you seen my first query?  Just change `COUNT(ID)` and `TABLE A` (I used the name you wrote in your question)

Comment: now i saw it thanks alot, but not sure if it also works with the application..ill try

Comment: i hope, other queries didnt work with the whole application

Comment: it gives 0 back

Comment: In the application, are you expecting a number or a string?  This select returns a string...(' is a character). For this reason Sami note.

Answer (score -2):

Use TOP statement in SQL server :

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM table a
```

Comment: i mean itgives for ex 9000 and i need 9'000

Comment: Provide your sample data and expected result.

Comment: SELECT count(id) FROM table a 35000 and i need 35'000

Comment: Will you need 35,000 or 35'000

Comment: i will need 35'000

Comment: And how does the `TOP` keyword influence the _formatting_ of the output?